# "emulator: warning: opening audio input failed" displayed in the console while AVD is launching

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

```
"emulator: warning: opening audio input failed"
```

The above message is displayed in the **console** everytime an **AVD is launching**, and then **no sound** is coming out from the emulator.

I have tried to **delete the AVD** and have created a new one again and again, but it didn't help with the problem.

I have also searched on Google for many time, but I find nothing useful.

It is really interesting that people tend to suggest to just ignore the problem because the AVD is still working fine without sound.

But I am writing an Android App that related to sound, I really need a workable solution to make the **AVD to "speak" again**.

Many thanks to you.

Comment: Did you try creating a new project?

Also, what is your target and min SDK?

Answer (score 5):

you can disable audio input setting manually : go to `your-avd-path/config.ini` then change the line `hw.audioInput=yes` to `hw.audioInput=no`

Comment: My path was something like: `C:..\..\.android\avd\My_First_App.avd\config.ini`

Comment: With that solution, I still got three lines of error:
`Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice 'goldfish_audio_in'
Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice 'adc'`

But at least it stopped the crazy looping error in the logcat!

Answer (score 3):

Open the AVD Manager.Click edit on any existing Virtual Device created or create a new one. On the create Virtual device Window, there is a **new** button on hardware tab.When that button is clicked, u will get a number of properties. Select the necessary property (like **Audio Playback Support**).    I think that will do the trick.

**EDIT**: This was possible in earlier versions of **AVD Manager**. Android updated the AVD to a new one(that we see now). There is no option to enable/disable audio/video in the new AVD creation window and there is no word of it in the [AVD documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html).

However they specify that you can play audio and video using Emulator.

> AVDs let you define certain hardware aspects of your emulated phone
>   and allow you to create many configurations to test many Android
>   platforms and hardware permutations. Once your application is running
>   on the emulator, it can use the services of the Android platform to
>   invoke other applications, access the network, **play audio and video**,
>   store and retrieve data, notify the user, and render graphical
>   transitions and themes.

Comment: This is not showing up on my AVD manager on any of my 3 development machines (all with different AVD versions from old to latest).

Comment: @Fro_oo This was possible in earlier versions of *AVD Manager*. Android updated the AVD to a new one(that we see now). There is no option to enable/disable audio/video in the new AVD creation window. So I assume there is no need to enable/disable it.

Comment: @RKN Sure. Anyway, impossible for me to make the emultaor work on Snow Leopard. Even if I've updated the sdk (info from this website http://ukblog.im-mobility.com/running-android-sdk-mac-os-106-snow-leopard). Well, e-bay cheap prices to the rescue... I'll buy a real device. :-)

Comment: No tab neither.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved my issue: Make sure you do not have anything else "using" or diverting your audio driver.

In my instance I also work with audio devices for music applications. This one in particular was "Jack Audio". So I disabled the Jack Audio server and my audio device came back.

Comment: In my case it was the webcam mic