# Android-Studio Emulator audio error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, virtual-machine

Hello, I am trying to setup **Android Studio 3.1.3** in a **guest VM** with windows 10 x64 pro. In the VirtualBox I have `intel HD sound controller` enabled. I have installed `Android 6.0` in AVD for `ARM EABI` architecture on a Pixel.

However, when I try to launch the emulator I get

```java
Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

Emulator: qemu-system-armel.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
```

and the emulator is just a black screen that does not respond to anything.

I have everything enabled in Virtual Box regarding hardware acceleration.

I checked these posts:

[Is it possible to run Android Device Emulator (via Android Studio 2) on VMWare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729150/is-it-possible-to-run-android-device-emulator-via-android-studio-2-on-vmware)

[“emulator: warning: opening audio input failed” displayed in the console while AVD is launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682829/emulator-warning-opening-audio-input-failed-displayed-in-the-console-while-a/21564682)

[Android Emulator: Audio Input Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234091/android-emulator-audio-input-failed?rq=1)

but I still get the same error and black screen on the emulator...

I have also tried to disable sound in `config.ini` or disable the microphone in windows 10 VM but didnt change anything.

**Am I missing something here?**

**Is it impossible to run android emulator for `ARM` architecture on a VM?**

Comment: Anyone out there facing the same problem?

Comment: Are you running in VMWare? Wasn't sure.  I've only tried on WMWare not other things like Oracle's VirtualBox.  Not sure if it will work. 
Also, at one point I needed this ability and couldn't get it working and I used https://www.genymotion.com/ Android In Cloud and it worked well.  You have to manage it though and it'll cost you $2 a day depending on how long you session is.  
Last thing, I've seen the error you're getting and I don't think I've ever solved it.  I just ended up creating another VM image and finally got it working by luck.

Comment: @raddevus Yes it is running in a windows 10 guest VM (VirtualBox). I am using Intel HD audio controller in VirtualBox settings since AC97 doesnt even work in the guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

Just to ansewer the question, for me the solution was to just use API version older than 23 (android 6.0). API 22 (android 5.1) seems to work well, althought you may notice some latency.

**NOTE:** *I ll leave the question open just in case there is a better way to make it work with latest android versions.*

Answer (score 0):

Plugin something in the microphone pin and voila.. the error goes away... for some reason, it needs the microphone .. AMD Ryzen 1600, the hypervisor is on, windows 10 pro-1903. Running Pie on emulator fine